Integrality gap of Maximum Coverage LP
Consider Maximum-Coverage problem, which means there are set $A$ and $n$ subsets of $A$, we can choose $k$ subsets to cover some elements, and Maximum-Coverage is the assignment that cover most elements in $A$. We know by LP relaxation there is $1-1/e$ approximation algorithm, however, the integrality gap for it is $1-1/e+\epsilon$, which means there is an instance $I$ such that $LP(I)=1$ and $Opt(I)<1-1/e+\epsilon$, how to choose the problem set $I$?

What do you mean by $LP(I) = 1$?

If the integrality gap is $1-\frac{1}{e} + \epsilon$, then by definition we have $LP(I) \ge \frac{OPT(I)}{1-\frac{1}{e} + \epsilon}$.

What do you mean by "choose the problem set $I$"? Do you mean you want to find an instance (not problem set) where this bound is tight?

Yes, I want to find a counterexample.

I am not sure what do you mean by 'counterexample'? I hope you are not trying to construct an instance which does not satisfy the inequality. Because there won't be any, as it is well-proven theoretical bound.

You can construct instances where $LP(I) = OPT(I)$, which would be the best. Similarly, you can find instances where the inequality is just barely satisfied (tight)!.

I would recommend you modify your question to better reflect your requirements.
